# Anyone here have an opinion on HeapAgent?

Tags: c++, heap-corruption, memory-corruption

I'm trying to track down some memory corruption going on in an app - I've heard of (but never used) Boundschecker. Rumour is that it's way to slow to use in a high performance application like a game (which is what the app I'm trying to fix is). 
 Has anyone here used HeapAgent and have anything (good or bad) to say about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience using Boundschecker or HeapAgent. But if you are trying to debug memory corruption or leaks, [Paul Nettle Memory Manager](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Presenting_A_Memory_Manager.shtml) is very good. I have used this memory manager to track down few nasty bugs in a game.

Comment: D'oh! Link to the zip file is dead :-(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be late to the game - HeapAgent is **fantastic**.

I've used it for years and find it superb in pretty much every way - it's very good at helping track down memory leaks, corruptions, etc., and their API documentation (which allows you to fine-tune the behavior) is among the best tech writing I've ever seen in a programming product.

For instance, server applications (such as I write) usually allocate a bunch of housekeeping memory at startup , and then enter a service loop. I didn't care about the housekeeping data, but I *did* care about a leak in every service loop.

So using the API, my app incremented the HeapAgent "checkpoint" at the top of every service loop, and the current checkpoint is attached to every allocation.

Using the GUI tool, it's easy to filter all with checkpoint >N, where N was the value at the entry to the service loop: we can see if there is stuff remaining behind after each loop.

If your service loop allocates something that **should** stick around after the end of the loop, you can mark that allocation as intended so that the "has anything leaked?" test won't complain about it.

Each allocation keeps track of the location where it was allocated from, as well as the callstack at the time, so your low-level helper functions ("mypersonalalloc(..)") still show who called *it*. It's found so much stuff...

Tech support has been excellent.

The downside is that the GUI is very badly dated, (ala Windows 3.1 - really!) but that's a minor issue that doesn't really affect the functionality.

I have not used any of the other products mentioned here or anywhere else, but I could not be more pleased with HeapAgent.

~~~ Steve ["happy customer only" disclaimer applies]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a trial for HeapAgent. It wasn't easy, MicroQuill aren't very fast to respond, but I got it eventually. I had a problem when wxWidgets defined its own memory allocation routines which conflicted with HeapAgent's (only when compiling a Debug build), and I asked whether the API (which seemed to be undocumented) allowed testing the heap from the code. I never got help or answers (though I did get an apology about not getting them).

It looks to me like MicroQuill doesn't really want to sell HeapAgent. It's an old app with a very old UI, which hasn't really been developed for a while. It only supports 32-bit apps and its error dialog boxes are small and cannot be resized. Apparently there's no one there which can help users with problems.

I still think it's a good concept, and it did help to an extent in finding a problem I had. I imagine that if I got some help with it I might have bought it. However given the response I had the only thing I can say is: contact MicroQuill for a trial and try it yourself.